# How to use the verb "to hope for" in the right tense for something that hasn’t happened yet?

Tags: grammaticality, formality, present-tense, future-tense, present-continuous

I am sending formal mail to a German company so I was wondering whether the following sentence is ok to use in that correspondence?

> We are hoping for the best results.

Does this sentence make any sense? Is it grammatical in English? Is it idiomatic?

Is this a use of the future tense, or if not, should it be and if so how?

Should I say *we* here when it’s just me writing the message?

Answer (score 1):

> We **are hoping** for the best results

Yes, the sentence above makes sense. The **present continuous** tense used in the OP's example, adds emphasis and a certain urgency to the statement, for instance, it might be said at the onset of an experimental medical therapy.

But normally, the **present simple** is used with [hope](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/hope)

> We **hope** for the best results

The present tense with *hope* expresses **future meaning**, e.g. *She hopes to pass the exam*, the exam is set in the future, but the people speaking are expressing a wish, or an aspiration, at that precise moment of time.

> We hope the results **will be** the best

This solution is also possible but it's rather less common than the former, and the meaning is identical.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/hope) says

> After hope, we often use present verb forms even when there is reference to the future:
>
> - **We hope** she passes her driving test next week.
> - **I** just **hope** the bus is on time tomorrow.

If the OP wanted to express a degree of uncertainty about the results, they could use the past continuous tense, e.g.

> **We were** rather **hoping** for the best results before making our final decision.

Without further context, it's difficult to know whether this last solution is preferable.